# How do i change the bullet point color on my google blog spot.

Tags: html, text, blogger

I have blog in google blogspot http://www.myfishcave.in/. 
I want to post new post.

When I add bullets to my text the color of the text is black and color of the bullet is black.

When I **preview** it the bullet color is turning grey and the text color is black. I want both to look the same. I tried looking into my HTML code, but did not find anything relating bullet color or preview. Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share the exact link of the post?

Comment: try the CSS `.post li {color:black;}`

Answer (score 0):

Relevant link: http://www.cryer.co.uk/resources/javascript/html_8_changing_bullet_colours.htm

Look like list style will apply to both text and bullets, so you have to put in separating tags for the text if you want to have the text and bullet points different colors.